# Implementation of callback or listener in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, listener

I just entered into python programming (i have experience with java).  I want to implement callback/listener in a class.  I confused with available samples.  I just implemented a sample.  Please guide me

my python class as follows

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__result = 0

    def connect(self):
        self.__result = 1
```

my main python code as follows

```
import myClass

def on_connect(result):
    print("Connected with result code "+result)

myclass = myClass()
myclass.on_connect = on_connect

myclass.connect()
```

I just wanted to receive result in on_connect method main code.  How to modify the myClass for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The connect happens in the context of the class instance, so why don't you want to handle it in the class?

Answer (score 2):

Let's add handlers to the class, with nice `add` method and general `fire` that calls the callbacks:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__result = 0
        self.on_connect = []

    def connect(self):
        self.__result = 1
        self.fire()

    def add_listener(self, listener):
        self.on_connect.append(listener)

    def fire(self):
        for listener in self.on_connect:
            listener(self.__result)
```

Then we only need to redo one thing in your main code - the way we add the listener.

```
import myClass

def on_connect(result):
    print("Connected with result code "+result)

myclass = myClass()
myclass.add_listener(on_connect)

myclass.connect()
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that accept the callback as argument:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, on_connect=None):
        self._result = 0
        # store callback reference in a variable
        self._on_connect = on_connect

    def connect(self):
        self._result = 1
        # if callback is defined and it is a function/method
        if self._on_connect and callable(self._on_connect):
            # Send the object instance to the callback, 
            # you may use the same callback for multiple objects.
            self._on_connect(self)

    def get_result(self):
        return self._result
```

Then:

```
import MyClass

def on_connect_callback(instance):
    print('Connected with result code {}'.format(
        instance.get_result()))

my_obj = MyClass(on_connect=on_connect_callback)
my_obj.connect()
```